# Rails 3.0 beta send_file issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have you any one try sending file to client_side
`send_file(url),send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png",:type => "image/png")`

it gives an error for any file which i am sending

> Proc:0xb74e606c@/home...../gems/actionpack-3.0.0.beta/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:95

as simple

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3860-streaming-pdf-file
Either upgrade to 3.0.0.beta1 or pass :stream => false to send_file.